# Custom parameters handler in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an action like this:

```
public JsonResult Action(String deviceId, Guid clientId)
```

So, according url (with parameters) will be like

www.site/ControllerName/Action?deviceId=123&clientId={some_guid}

There is no secret, that if it is impossible to parse {some_guid} into **Guid** type, asp.net will generate an error.
The matter is in case of such wrong formatted requests I need the server to return special **JSON** result with message like { "result":"1"; "comments":"wrong url. review the parameter *clientId*" }.
How can I check action parameters before executing?

Comment: is the parameter "deviceId" meant to only allow numbers, or characters too?

Comment: This is simple string type. In this case it contains letters, numbers and '-' symbol.

Comment: Not really possible to provide a proper answer without more information. You've wrote in comment to one of the answers that you're trying to return a JSON object - is there more details you're hiding?

Comment: @ebb, it doesn't matter. I just want to know how to handle action parameters parsing by myself. But almost everybody advices me to redirect user to 404 page. It isn't thing I need.

Comment: Then please tell us what you need then, instead of saying "no, not good enough".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep what you had but make the parameters nullable;

```
public ActionResult Action(String deviceId, Guid? clientId)
{
     if (clientId.HasValue)
     {
         // Do something
     }
     else
     {
         throw new HttpException(404, "Url not found");
     }
 }
```

I realise this is almost the same as above, only here you are able to keep your types the same as your original post just checking to see if values have been passed

Answer (score 3):

I would change your signature to:

```
public ActionResult Action(String deviceId, string clientId)
```

then you can

```
Guid id;
if (!Guid.TryParse(clientId, out id))
{
   // take appropiate action
}
```

Comment: Why the use of ModelState.AddModelError() when its a get request? - Also, it doesnt make sense to throw a custom error in such scenario. If the user is trying to access a URL which dosent exist then return a httpexception with code 404.

Comment: @ebb. The matter is result of this action is json object. I need to return { "result":"1"; "comments":"wrong clienId" } in case of wrong url format.

Comment: yea, it is one of the possible solutions, but I wonder if any another ways provided by MVC.

Comment: @ebb, indeed AddModelError does not fit very well in there. I have removed it. Thx! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the ModelBinder for that and make the `Guid.TryParse` check there. If something has a wrong value, you can modify ModelState.

The second approach is to use somewhat special action filter attribute like that `HandleErrorAttribute` bundled with ASP.NET MVC. That filter could catch that particular type of exception and provide a specific error handling workflow and result substitution (probably the best idea here is just redirect to 404, because "wrong Guid" is nothing else but "non-existent page").

Comment: I don't need to redirect user to another page. It is nesessary to alert user about wrong parameter format in action result. The matter is result of this action is json object. I need to return { "result":"1"; "comments":"wrong clienId" } in case of wrong url format.

Comment: @JooLio, actually I didn't mean redirecting. I meant just use 404 status code and appropriate page for such a page. But you just told me about completely different story - JSON. Please mention that detail in the original post.

Comment: Also, you'd better re-read my answer. I proposed 404 just as a possible scenario of "custom workflow handling". You may just push any predefined JSON to the client with the same success.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
public ActionResult Action(int deviceId, string clientId)
{
    Guid clientGuid;

    if (!Guid.TryParse(clientId, out clientGuid))
    {
        throw new HttpException(404, "Action not found");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some cool stuff....
    }
}
```